# WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified (when path too long?) in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, windowserror

I'm making a script(python 2.7) to find all files in a directories and its subdirectories and then to fetch its last modification data.

In order to do this, I use the hardcoded path in os.walk to walk through the directories.

The problem is that some files produce the above-mentioned error when opened. The most common reason people run into this problem is because the path is not correctly joined, thereby causing the script to try and open a file that doesn't exist. This isn't the case for me.

After trying different combinations of directories, I began to notice a pattern whereby files that produce the error seem to have a deep directory structure and a long filename. I can't think of any other reason for the issue.

After searching for solutions I came across:
Adding `"\\\\?\\"` as a prefix to the path.

However it does not seem to work, Most probably because the file name may not be unicode. As this is a file accessed from the server, not much we can do about that.
The format of path that i am using is:
`"//xyz.zone1.zifi.net/DavWWWRoot/sites/abc/1324324/mywork"`

Any other solutions are appreciated?

Comment: Windows limits paths to 260 characters, and some of your paths are probably too long. There are workarounds for this: for example, by assigning a drive letter to some intermediate folder using `subst`.

Comment: yes each time joining the filename/foldername to the path makes it lengthy and unable for windows to open when path length reacehs above 260 characters. Can you please explain the workaround and how to open the path >260 characters

Comment: Well, as I said, you could use `subst` to assign a drive letter to some intermediate directory.